# Check if UIImage property got assigned or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIImage` property, and after shooting image from iPhone camera I assigned image object to this property, otherwise not.
How can I check if this property contains image after shooting or not?
Below my code didn't help.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIView<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageShot;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize imageShot = _imageShot;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _imageShot = [[UiImage alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.imageShot = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}

- (void)buttonClick {
    if (_imageShot) {

    } 
    else {

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Set `_shoted_image` in `init` to `nil` and allocate it only when you get image froma camera.

Comment: Reading, ohh hang start again...aahan aahan...ohh damn start reading again! duh no luck!

Comment: ShootedImage?  The past tense of shoot is shot.  Your variable should be imageShot, not shootedImage.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `init`, you should create `shotedImage` with `nil` instead of alloc'ing a new, empty image. That'll allow to perform tests like `if (!shotedImage)` (as `nil == 0`).

Comment: how can I know image assigned to property or not after shooting from camera?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does your code do when shooting?